# String Manipulation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, string

Is there any way of setting an "Column Alias" in SQL Server?

For Example i have two columns. Description and Price

```
ID    colDescription                                colPrice
1     Red ball costs %colPrice% dollars             2
2     Blue ball costs %colPrice% dollars            3
```

The selection of colDescription for ID=2, should fetch

**Blue ball costs 3 dollars**

Comment: That's not a column alias - that's string substitution

Comment: Oups! I now got the point! But string substitution is the only way? Another way of referencing the value does not exist? (I am sorry about my English).

Comment: Depends on what do you exactly want to do with the data. You could have a trigger that updates the other column, you could have a computed column.

Comment: 3 dollars for blue ball?

Comment: Don't worry about it! You may order the red one! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Computed Column since you're on SQL Server 2005:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx

Comment: It's an extremely fast and efficient mechanism, however I prefer to abstract out presentation and business logic from the data store myself.

Answer (score 2):

The manual way to do so would be:

```
select replace(coldescription,'%colPrice%',colprice) from table
```